# PHP DOMDocument: Get Null if no nodeValue

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, nodevalue

Here is my php:

```
$drmMediaId=$drmNode->getElementsByTagName("media_id")->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

And here is my drmNode

```
<drm>
    <type>no_media</type>
    <media_id></media_id>
</drm>
```

In that case, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object".

I would like a NULL in my $drmMediaId. Do I have to test existence of nodeValue each time for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to check the existence of something before you access it.

Comment: Ok, in that case I think the best way is to do something like that:
`$drmMediaId=isset($drmNode->getElementsByTagName("media_id")->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue)?`
`$drmNode->getElementsByTagName("media_id")->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue:NULL;`

Comment: That can be shortened by using the [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) which was introduced in PHP 7.0.